# mysql check columns?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Is there a way to check what columns are there in mysql syntax?

For example,

```
$dbh = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table");
while($row = $dbh->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
$row['somecolumn'];
}
```

For instance, if there is or not somecolumn, I would like to find out if there is a way that will display a list of ALL the columns in the syntax I'm looking for in `table`

This way in the future, I'll be able to check if there is `$row['fr']` or `$row['food']` that can work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply check whether  `$row` contains the key you need.

The PHP function [`array_key_exists`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) will tell you whether `$row` contains the key you want. For instance, `array_key_exists("fr", $row)` will return true if `$row` contains an `fr` key.

If you want to see all the keys (i.e. all the columns), simply use [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php); for example : `array_keys($row)` will give you all the keys in `$row`.

Alternatively, if you don't mind another SQL call, you can use `SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name='your_table'` as xdazz's answer mentions.

Comment: I don't want to check if it is null or not, i would like it to display exactly what the columns are

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` to do this, or `DESCRIBE`.

Take a look at the [information_schema columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/columns-table.html) documentation, or see the [describe](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/describe.html) syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the sql below to select cloumn names for one table.

```
SELECT 
    column_name 
FROM 
    information_schema.columns 
WHERE 
    table_name='your_table';
```